# Using Picklists and MultiPicklists with Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, css

I'm creating a visualforce page that I plan to run in Classic and SF1 (and eventually Lightning) but I'm struggling a little bit with the design and functionality of the picklists/multipicklists.

I have tried to use the Lightning Design System but it appears that new picklist fields are being wrapped in  tags so are not holding the design.  This is of course using the standard  tags.  I looked at trailhead and at the examples in the LDS page and those use standard html tags and I'd have to completely build out and maintain the picklist values and behaviour, which is not ideal.  The trailhead examples use basic input text components and use remote objects, but even if I moved over to use remote objects, it will not fix my style and hard coding issue with the picklists.

We are not geared towards lightning yet, so no aura or actual lightning code is being utilized yet.

Does anyone have any suggestions or experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have figured out the issue.  It seems as though salesforce is stripping out the styleClass property on a newer field in Salesforce1.  I added it in jquery and had to put a setTimeout on it to add a class back to it after the page loads and at the end.